# Why are closed or migrated questions listed in the "related" box?

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions

Looking at the downvoted question https://serverfault.com/questions/297473/unable-to-browse-hosted-site-on-server you can see on the right side the "Related" box. At the second item you find https://serverfault.com/questions/60880/coolest-web-site-name-closed.

Isn't it a stupid thing to relate a closed or migrated question to another question? It is not constructive to click on a link that leads you to a closed question. So they shouldn't be advertised in that way. Or am I totally wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Being closed or migrated doesn't mean the question has no value. Relevant answers may have been provided before (or whilst) the community decided that the question should be closed or migrated.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a question state like "no value" then?

Comment: They will most likely be deleted by mods and or 10k+ users voting to do so.